# Use of class and functions to provide info about rectangle

Tags: c++, function, class, loops

One of my last assignments in C++ course is to write this program:

> Reads a name for rectangle and just accepts names like "rec" name. for
>   example "rec john" "rec sally" ...
>   Then asks from bottom left point x 
>   and y, as well as height and length. Then displays some info including
>   BL point, area, perimeter,...

Here is the code I wrote. I was working on it for a long time so now I really cannot see what is wrong with it. So please help.

My code:

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    double px;
    double py;

public:
    void setX(const double x);
    void setY(const double y);
    double getX() const;
    double getY() const;
};

class Rectangle
{
private:
    string name;
    Point blPoint;
    double length, height;

public:
    void setName(const string & inName);
    void setBottomLeft(const double x, const double y);
    void setDimensions(const double inLength, const double inHeight);

    string getName() const;
    Point getBottomLeft() const;
    double getLength() const;
    double getHeight() const;

    double area() const;
    double perimeter() const;
    Point midPoint() const;
    void scaleBy2();
    void display() const;
};
void welcome();
bool read_rect (const string promptName, const string errInvalidName, const string errUsedName, string & inName, vector<Rectangle> & list);
void readXYcoord (const string promptPointxy, double & xcord, double & ycord);
void readLH (const string promptLH, double & inLength, double & inHeight);
void addRect (const string Name, double x, double y, double inLength, double inHeight, vector<Rectangle> & list);
void dis_rec(vector<Rectangle> & list);

int main()
{

    Rectangle rec;
    vector<Rectangle>list;
    string prompt1stName = "Enter the name of the first rectangle: ";
    string promptName = "Enter the name of the next rectangle: ";
    string errInvalidName = "Invalid input. Type 'rec' following by the name or 'stop' if done.";
    string errUsedName = "This name is already being used!";
    string inName;
    string Name;

    double x,y,length,height;

    welcome ();
    bool read = read_rect (prompt1stName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);

    while (read == false)
    {
        cout << "Try again! ";
        read = read_rect (prompt1stName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);
    }

    if (inName != "stop")
    {
        int a = inName.length() - 4;
        Name = inName.substr(4,a);

        double x, y;
        string promptPointxy = "Enter " + Name + "'s bottom left x and y coords: ";
        readXYcoord (promptPointxy, x, y);

        double length, height;
        string promptLH= "Enter " + Name + "'s length and height: ";
        readLH (promptLH, length, height);

        addRect(Name, x, y, length, height, list);
    }

    while (inName !="stop")
    {
        cout << "Thank you! ";
        bool read = read_rect(promptName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);

        while (read == false)
        {
            cout << "Try again! " <<endl;
            read = read_rect(promptName, errInvalidName, errUsedName, inName, list);
        }

        if (inName != "stop")
        {
            int a = inName.length() - 4;
            Name = inName.substr(4, a);

            double x, y;
            string promptPoint = "Enter " + Name + "'s bottom left x and y coords: ";
            readXYcoord(promptPoint, x, y);

            double inLength, inHeight;
            string promptLength = "Enter " + Name + "'s length and height: ";
            readLH(promptLength, inLength, inHeight);

            addRect(Name, x, y, inLength, inHeight, list);
        }
    }

    if (list.size() != 0)
    {
        dis_rec(list);
    }

    else
    {

        cout << "You have no rectangles in your list." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

void welcome()
{
    cout << "Welcome! Create your own list of rectangles." << endl;
    cout << "You will be asked to provide information about each rectangle in your list by name." << endl;
    cout << "Type the word 'stop' for the rectangle name when you are done." << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

bool read_rect (const string promptName, const string errInvalidName, const string errUsedName, string & inName, vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    cout << promptName;
    getline(cin, inName);
    if (inName == "stop")
    {
        return (true);
    }
    else if (inName.substr(0,4) != "rec ")
    {
        cout<< errInvalidName <<endl;
        return (false);
    }
    else
    {
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (inName == "rec " + list[i].getName())
            {
                j = j+1;
            }
        }
        if (j == 0)
        {
            return(true);
        }
        if (j != 0)
        {
            cout << errUsedName;
            return(false);
        }
    }
}

void readXYcoord (const string promptPointxy, double & xcord, double & ycord)
{
    cout << promptPointxy;
    cin >> xcord;
    cin >> ycord;
}

void readLH (const string promptLH, double & inLength, double & inHeight)
{
    cout<< promptLH;
    cin >> inLength;
    cin >> inHeight;
    cout << endl;
    while (inLength <= 0 || inHeight <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Make length and height positive values. Try again.";
        cout << promptLH;
        cin >> inLength;
        cin >> inHeight;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void addRect (const string Name, double x, double y, double inLength, double inHeight, vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    Rectangle rec;
    rec.setName(Name);
    rec.setBottomLeft(x, y);
    rec.setDimensions(inLength, inHeight);
    list.push_back(rec);
}

void dis_rec(vector<Rectangle> & list)
{
    cout<<"You have "<<list.size()<<" rectangle(s) in your list: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"Rectangle '"<<list[i].getName()<<"': ";
        list[i].display();
        cout<<"After scale by 2:";
        list[i].scaleBy2();
        list[i].display();
    }
}
void Point::setX(const double x)
{
    px = x;
}

void Point::setY(const double y)
{
    py = y;
}

double Point::getX() const
{
    return (px);
}

double Point::getY() const
{
    return (py);
}

void Rectangle::setName(const string & inName)
{
    name = inName;
}

void Rectangle::setBottomLeft(const double x, const double y)
{
    blPoint.setX(x);
    blPoint.setY(y);
}

void Rectangle::setDimensions(const double inLength, const double inHeight)
{
    length = inLength;
    height = inHeight;
}

string Rectangle::getName() const
{
    return (name);
}

Point Rectangle::getBottomLeft() const
{
    return (blPoint);
}

double Rectangle::getLength() const
{
    return (length);
}

double Rectangle::getHeight() const
{
    return (height);
}

double Rectangle::area() const
{
    return(length*height);
}

double Rectangle::perimeter() const
{

    return ( (height*2)+(length*2));
}

Point Rectangle::midPoint() const
{

    Point midPoint;
    double mpx = blPoint.getX() + 0.5 * length;
    double mpy = blPoint.getY() + 0.5 * height;
    midPoint.setX(mpx);
    midPoint.setY(mpy);
    return(midPoint);
}

void Rectangle::scaleBy2()
{
    double mx = blPoint.getX() + 0.5 * length;
    double my = blPoint.getY() + 0.5 * height;
    double newmdx = mx - length;
    double newmdy = my - height;
    length= 2* length;
    height = 2* height;
    blPoint.setX(newmdx);
    blPoint.setY(newmdy);
}

void Rectangle::display() const
{
    cout << " Location is (" << blPoint.getX() << ", " << blPoint.getY() << "), length is " << length << ", height is " << height << "; Area is " << area() << "; perimeter is " << perimeter() << ", midpoint is located at (" << midPoint().getX() << ", " << midPoint().getY() << ")" << endl;
}
```

here is the corrects output for correct input:

```
Welcome! Create your own list of rectangles.
You will be asked to provide information about each rectangle in your list by name.
Type the word 'stop' for the rectangle name when you are done.

Enter the name of the first rectangle: rec john
Enter john's bottom left x and y coords: 2
3
Enter john's length and height: 4
5

Thank you! Enter the name of the next rectangle: stop

You have 1 rectangle(s) in your list:

Rectangle 'john': Location is (2, 3), length is 4, height is 5; Area is 20, perimeter is 18, midpoint is located at (4, 5.5)
     After scale by 2: Location is (0, 0.5), length is 8, height is 10; Area is 80, perimeter is 36, midpoint is located at (4, 5.5)
```

and here is my program's response:

```
Welcome! Create your own list of rectangles.
You will be asked to provide information about each rectangle in your list by na
me.
Type the word 'stop' for the rectangle name when you are done.

Enter the name of the first rectangle: rec john
Enter john's bottom left x and y coords: 2
3
Enter john's length and height: 4
5

Thank you! Enter the name of the next rectangle: Invalid input. Type 'rec' follo
wing by the name or 'stop' if done.
Try again!
Enter the name of the next rectangle: stop
You have 1 rectangle(s) in your list:
Rectangle 'john':  Location is (2, 3), length is 4, height is 5; Area is 20; per
imeter is 18, midpoint is located at (4, 5.5)
After scale by 2: Location is (0, 0.5), length is 8, height is 10; Area is 80; p
erimeter is 36, midpoint is located at (4, 5.5)
```

As you can see, the only problem with this program is it displays the errInvalidName before asking for the next rectangle's name and info. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in combining `cin >>` with `getline`. Those two things aren't quite compatible, since they use a different mechanism to get the input. To fix the problem, after every `cin >>` in your program, you should also add `cin.ignore()`.

The difference between those two methods is, that the overloaded `operator >>` gets the content **before** the newline character, and **leaves** the newline char in the buffer. When you use `getline` after doing `>>`, you **extract** the empty line. The empty line isn't "stop", and doesn't begin with "rec", so your program prompts an error.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use just cin and it did not work. can you explain why cin alone is not working here?

Comment: `cin >>` extracts the data to the moment it encounters a whitespace. Your data is `rec something`, so it cointains a space, which is a whitespace.

Comment: oh ok. :) Thanks. So here I have to use "getline" to cover this. and I have to add "cin.ignore()" immediately after "getline(cin, inName)"? I'm not sure where to add it

Comment: After `cin >>` or before `getline`. You should **always** use `cin.ignore()` after a `cin >>` if you plan to use `getline`.

Comment: So add a an `ignore()` after every `cin <<` (instead of the one before `getline`). And check the other answer by MeNa.